# $exception->getMessage alternate way

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-5.3, handler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAJXL.png)

in laravel 5.3 Exception handler file Exception doesn't sent the exception message
$exception->getMessage(); is null is their is any other way to get the exception message ..? or how can i resolve this issue..?

Comment: Can you show part of your code?

Comment: public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {dd($exception);
     
        if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {

        } else {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        }
        // return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

Comment: simple laravel default functionality...but $exception->getMessage(); was empty .... This is the issue only....!

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it works. Maybe your issue not in render()?

Comment: can you suggest any other places is this issue occur....because still i am getting this issue.. But $exception->getStatusCode(); was return the correct status code...  $exception->getStatusCode(); $exception->getLine(); $exception->getFile();   but $exception->getMessage();. only issue

Comment: in your controller method write  `throw new HttpException(400, "message");` and see, what happens.